# Sql server datetime is interpreted with wrong day/month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query that is something like

```
select * from myTable where [date] < 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

However sql server is interpreting this in the format YYYY-DD-MM (I thought the YYYY-MM-DD format was used as it shouldn't be unambiguous, but obliviously this isn't the case!)

It would be good to know why this has happened (I haven't expereinced this before with sql server, and what the best practice is when dealing with dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three formats that are (and have been for a long time) unambiguous. These are:

```
 YYYYMMDD
 YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss
 YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.mil
```

Some other formats *may* be unambiguous on newer versions of SQL Server and/or working with the newer `datetime2`, `date` and `time` types, but you can always rely on the above 3. So just either use `YYYYMMDD` or, if possible, avoid passing *strings* to SQL Server when you want to deal with dates.

(Or, option 3, use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) and specify exactly what format you're actually using)

Answer (score 0):

I would start with two things to check:

1. How this date is passed to SQL Server (it can depends on date
   settings on client -- i.e. Windows settings). I saw a code (in VB6)
   which passes date like '2014-10-08' as 8th Oct 2014 or 10th August
   2014 depends on server settings (Polish, British, American).
2. How SQL Server recognizes the date passed as string -- i.e. `2014-10-08` (similar issue).